# Onomatopoeia Charades #1

Tags: onomatopoeia-charades

What object or device makes this sound?

Mrouw-ouw-ouw-ouw-ouw-ouw-mmmmmmmmm

---

Keep em comin' everybody. I'll leave it open for a couple more days so everybody can get a chance to guess.

---

Valiant efforts everybody! I wish I could up vot you all many times.

ANSWER:

A dishwasher going into it's drying cycle.

Comment: LOL I was joking when I suggested this, but this might prove to be a very fun game. ;)

Comment: I know.  Luckily I have no sense of humour.

Answer (score 7):

[Dubstep](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfnDRA4t1ms).

Comment: That may just be the best thing I've ever seen.

Comment: lol. you win!!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go for a 1998 Honda Civic starting from cold.

Answer (score 3):

maybe a didjeridoo?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a light saber turning on and then a slow swing

Answer (score 1):

A bee hive driving off?

Comment: Bees can drive?

Comment: Not very well... Their hives have no windshield, they can't see jack!

Answer (score 1):

That must be the Easter Bunny

Comment: Ain't no eggs in that basket. 

Answer (score 1):

a dog in heat makes that noise

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a '67 Camaro when you make your voice rough enough.

Answer (score 1):

a cat at night meowing while clawing at the room door trying to get in.